# Is there a way in java to write a method that gets 2 arrays that must be the same length?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to write a private method in java that receives 2 arrays.
is there a way to make that they have to be the same length?

something like:

public static void method(int[] arr1 , int[] arr2[arr1.length])

Comment: Not in the method's signature and not at compile time. But we can validate the length in the method's body and, for example, throw an `Exception` if they do not match: `if (arr1.length != arr2.length) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("arrays \"arr1\" and \"arr2\" must have same length."); }`.

Comment: @Turing85  approach is correct

Comment: Sometimes, not very often, you may be better off storing a single array of pairs rather than a pair of arrays, so it may also be worth checking if that is true for your actual use case. (For example if you have a set of points, storing all the `x` coordinates in one array and all the `y` coordinates in another can usually be replaced with an array of `x-y` pairs.)

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the method's signature and not at compile time. But we can validate the lengths in the method's body and, for example, throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if they do not match:

```
public static void method(int[] arr1 , int[] arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("arrays \"arr1\" and \"arr2\" must have same length."); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the Apache Commons Lang3 library, it provides [a way via `ArrayUtils.isSameLength()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#isSameLength-int:A-int:A-):

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

// ...

private static void method(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    if (!ArrayUtils.isSameLength(arr1, arr2)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays must be same length");
    }
    // ...
}
```

This does have the quirk, like many other methods of the class, of treating a `null` argument the same as a 0-length array instead of raising a `NullPointerException`. May or may not be desirable depending on what you're doing.